# ASP.NET MVC4 Arraylist from controller to view

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-mvc-4, arraylist

i have an problem with my arraylist i can't read it out in the view

here i have the code

DB: here i read out the data out of the database

```
ArrayList result = new ArrayList();

        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ArrayList temp = new ArrayList();
                temp.Add(reader["Voornaam"].ToString());
                temp.Add(reader["Tussenvoegsel"].ToString());
                temp.Add(reader["Achternaam"].ToString());
                temp.Add(reader["Adres"].ToString());
                temp.Add(reader["Postcode"].ToString());
                temp.Add(reader["Plaats"].ToString());
                temp.Add(reader["Land"].ToString());
                temp.Add(reader["Geboortedatum"].ToString());
                temp.Add(reader["Telefoonnummer"].ToString());
                temp.Add(reader["Mobielnummer"].ToString());
                temp.Add(reader["Email"].ToString());
                result.Add(temp);
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        else
        {

        }
        return result;
```

Controller: make arraylist gebruikers and send it to the view

```
DB dbase = new DB();
            ArrayList Gebruikers = dbase.getGebruikerALL(Session["Bid"].ToString());
            return View(Gebruikers);
```

View: read out the array in the foreach

```
@model IEnumerable<EventRentalSystem.Models.ProfielModels>
@foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gebruikersnaam)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Voornaam)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tussenvoegsel)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Achternaam)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Adres)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Postcode)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Plaats)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Land)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Geboortedatum)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Telefoonnummer)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mobielnummer)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)</td>
                                    <td><a class="edit" href="javascript:;">Bewerk</a></td>
                                    <td><a class="delete" href="javascript:;">Verwijder</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            }
```

and still get the error:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[EventRentalSystem.Models.ProfielModels]'.

Anyone know how i can read out the array in the view?

Comment: the error message is quite clear.

Comment: You are mixing an `ArrayList` (which accepts a list of any object) and a strongly typed `IEnumerable<>`. Pick one (prefer the strongly typed one).

Comment: How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Razor view is expecting the IEnumerable of ProfielModels Modal type.But you are passing the type of ArrayList which is not implementing IEnumerable where List does. 
So first define your modal class as below

```
public class ProfielModels
{
    public string Voornaam { get; set; }
    public string Tussenvoegsel { get; set; }
    public string Achternaam { get; set; }
    public string Adres { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string Plaats { get; set; }
    public string Land { get; set; }
    public string Geboortedatum { get; set; }
    public string Telefoonnummer { get; set; }
    public string Mobielnummer { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Then bind your database values into modal obejcts

List<`ProfileModels`> ListModal = List<`ProfileModels`> ();

```
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ProfielModels temp = new ProfielModels();
            temp.Voornaam = reader["Voornaam"].ToString();
            temp.Tussenvoegsel = reader["Tussenvoegsel"].ToString();
            temp.Achternaam = reader["Achternaam"].ToString();
            temp.Adres = reader["Adres"].ToString();
            temp.Postcode = reader["Postcode"].ToString();
            temp.Plaats = reader["Plaats"].ToString();
            temp.Land = reader["Land"].ToString();
            temp.Geboortedatum = reader["Geboortedatum"].ToString();
            temp.Telefoonnummer = reader["Telefoonnummer"].ToString();
            temp.Mobielnummer = reader["Mobielnummer"].ToString();
            temp.Email = reader["Email"].ToString();
            ListModal.Add(temp);
        }
```

//And finally change your controller code as below to return the objetct whic implements IEnumerable

`DB dbase = new DB();`

`List<ProfielModels> ListModal= dbase.getGebruikerALL(Session["Bid"].ToString());`
 `return View(Gebruikers);`

Answer (score 0):

Use, for example, `List<T>`.

If you come from a Java background: the `ArrayList` in C# is a lot more archaic than the `ArrayList<T>` in Java: the correct alternative is a `List<T>`.
An `ArrayList` in C# can take any type of object whereas the majority of your cases will be better suited with a strongly typed collection.

Here are a few things to consider:

Create a wrapper class.

Right now you're retrieving the data from a `User` and you're just placing them in an arraylist after converting them all to a string representation. This is horrible: you don't have easy access to the values, the values will require casting for further usage, etc.

Instead create a class `User` and store those fields in there

```
class User {
 public string FirstName { get; set; }
 public string LastName { get; set; }
 // Other properties
}
```

Now you can just fill it up like this:

```
while (reader.Read()) {
 User user= new User();
 user.FirstName = reader["Voornaam"]);
 user.LastName = reader["Achternaam"]);

 result.Add(user);
}
```

Since `List<T>` is an `IENumerable<T>` whereas `ArrayList` isn't, your problem will be solved.

Sidenote: Properties start with an uppercase, local variables with lowercase.